# Nested type: struct vs class

Tags: c++, c++11, inner-classes

When should I define members in a struct inside a class and when should I define members in a nested class?

For example:

```
class SkypeProtocol
{
public:
    SkypeProtocol();
    virtual ~SkypeProtocol(){}

private:

    class SkypeProtocolDateTime
    {
    private:
        UI32 uDate;
        ERROR GetDateString(PUCHAR pcBuffer,PUI32 uBufLen);
    };

};
```

or

```
class SkypeProtocol
{
private:
    SkypeProtocol();
    virtual ~SkypeProtocol(){}

    typedef struct SkypeProtocolDateTime
    {
    private:
        UI32 uDate;
        ERROR GetDateString(PUCHAR pcBuffer,PUI32 uBufLen);
    }SSKYPE_STRUCT;

};
```

Comment: typedef struct { ...} structname is veeery C style (not C++), use just use "struct"

Comment: I didn't even know it was possible to declare a class inside a class. Is that common use?

Comment: @steffen yes, think iterators

Comment: @OMGtechy: so I /did/ know it was possible. :)

Answer (score 6):

In C++ there is no difference between class and struct except for default visibility of members (private for class, public for structs).

If your object will be used only for storage (without much logic implemented in itself) then it is common practice to create it as a struct, and use class only for more complex objects.

BTW: in C++ you do not need to use `typedef struct {...} StructName;` notation, plain `struct StructName {...};` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SkypeProtocolDateTime;
class SkypeProtocol
{
public:
    SkypeProtocol();
    virtual ~SkypeProtocol(){}

private:
    class SkypeProtocolDateTime* m_pimpl;
};
```

I prefer not expose my privates.

Comment: SkypeProtocolDateTime does not need to be defined at same scope as SkypeProtocol - it also can be nested class (defined in .cpp as `class SkypeProtocol::SkypeProtocolDateTime { ... };`). But yeah, that's my preferred way to create Pimpls :)

Comment: Agree, I have been known to do both.

Comment: It would be even better to do `std::unique_ptr< SkypeProtocolDateTime > m_dateTime_pimpl;`

Answer (score 0):

Nested classes not preferable which can really confuse sometimes. If you really want to use in this way struck is ok.

When you nest a class, you are probably ihntering in and somehow keep the more data in secret, but oop class designs also suggest that to split each class even if you want use some in other.

Private memory functions is a subject that can solve your problem, so read and dig in ;)

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to use struct for behavior-less or passive objects. It may contain CONSTANTS but lack functionality all-together. Date members are supposed to access directly instead of using getter and setter method since it has default public visibility. Actually it is part of google c++ style guide and also very clean way to handle user defined types.